# PHP - display string ISO-8859-2

Tags: php, collation

I have a mysql db - > column (Collation - latin2_general_ci) with this string : *Alb complet, cu sticlă albă Satinato cu şlefuire în faţete*
When i print the data from db in a php file i get : *Alb complet, cu sticl? alb? Satinato cu ?lefuire în fa?ete*

```
html :
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
```

Any ideas why and how can i solve this?

Comment: Did you set up PHP - Mysql connection encoding to latin2 ?

Comment: Collation (how to sort this column) is not what's important, character set is. Make sure latin2 is the character set of the column and the connection.

Comment: mysql_query ('SET NAMES latin2');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meta-tag, database encoding end connection encoding should be same.

Try query

```
SET NAMES encoding_name
```

before any query after connection

Old data may be lost, but new one should works correct

Comment: mysql_query ('SET NAMES latin2');